# MPI_Wtime() is returning 0

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I am compiling the following code using openMPI version 4.0.1 on linux and `MPI_Wtime()` is returning 0. I am compiling using mpicc -o testCode myfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Initialize MPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // printf("%d\n",MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE);

    // Get the clock precision and start the clock.
    double precision = MPI_Wtick();
    double starttime = MPI_Wtime();

    // Get this processor's rank and the size of the world.
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank ==0)
        printf("start time = %g\n", starttime);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MPI_Wtime` is not the current time, it's the time elapsed since an arbitrary "start time", which could very well be the time of the first call. The only guarantee you have is that if you call it multiple times, the various calls will use the same base time. So it doesn't make much sense to call it only once.

Comment: But is the arbitrary start time always the same?

Comment: I was told it was a "decent" way to generate an initial seed for stochastic simulations.

Comment: Well, `int i = 42;` is a decent initial seed for a simulation. It really depends what kind of randomness you expect.

Comment: @Zulan I disagree. I would be supplying that myself, by using something like time/clock, the randomness is done in the program without me having to prescribe the initial seed.

Comment: What's the difference between a simulation run where the "external randomness" yields `42` as a seed and you supply `42` as a seed? Is one of the results valid while the other is not?

Comment: No not at all. But having the user feed a different random integer everytime seems silly.